# R prompting [1] 1 while running a function

Tags: r, prompt

I prepared a fairly complex R function which is running nicely. However, each time is running it R fills the screen with the following expression:

```
  [1] 1
  [1] 1
  [1] 1
  [1] 1
  [1] 1
  [1] 1
```

I was wondering if there is a way to avoid this prompting from R. Here I can give you an example of the function:

```
y=function(x){
    results=rep(0, length(x))
    for (i in (1:length(x))) {
          if (x[i]>0) {
                     results[i]=u(x)
                    } 
    }
}

u=function(x){
             output=x+1
             return(output)
}
```

Comment: `y` returns no things to me. `u` returns just one value.

Comment: replace `return(output)` by `invisible(output)`

Comment: you could also replace the loop with an  `ifelse`

Answer (score 0):

You could  look into `sink("NUL")`, like so:

```
u(9)
#[1] 10
sink("NUL")
u(9)
sink()
u(9)
#[1] 10
```

Comment: I wish to thank you all for the contribution. I found what was the issue, it was related to some subfunctions output.

Comment: You could add your own solution as an answer and accept it